# Jboss 7 deploy struts war file

Tags: jboss7.x, struts-1

When i try to deploy war file in jboss 7 AS server i got following error

```
23:23:07,111 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."testapp.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."testapp.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "testapp.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.LabelledTag with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.testapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/struts/util/MessageResources;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2509) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1819) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources from [Module "deployment.testapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    ... 15 more

23:23:07,118 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 7) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "testapp.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"testapp.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"testapp.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"testapp.war\""}}
23:23:07,206 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment testapp.war in 87ms
23:23:07,206 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 7) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."testapp.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."testapp.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "testapp.war"
```

Comment: Seems the MessageResource class is not packed in your application or provided as a module. You should add more information about your war structure and how you add the struts classes.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when you try to deploy an ear/war/jar deployment in jboss7/wildfly and you have not specified what dependencies need your application.

Jboss7/Wildfly has his own module class loader to isolate applications and dependencies running into the same java virtual machine.
All deployments in jboss/wildfly are loaded as modules (not only the content included in modules folder, the content of deployments folder are modules too).

If you don't have packaged "struts" jar into the application deployment file, you will need to deploy the required dependencies as modules and tell to jboss that your application depends on it.

So, you have at least five alternatives:

1. Build your application as an Uber-Jar including your dependencies
   inside.
2. Deploy your application and dependencies in the deployments folder and add a manifest entry in your application to tell to jboss that
   your application depends on it.
3. Deploy your application and application dependencies (jars) in the deployments folder and add a jboss deployment descriptor xml in your
   application to tell to jboss that your application depends on it.
4. Deploy your application in the deployments folder and create modules for your dependencies (if do not exist) and add a manifest
   entry in your application to tell to jboss that your application
   depends on it.
5. Deploy your application in deployments folder and create modules for your dependencies (if do not exist) and use a jboss deployment
   descriptor xml in your application to tell to jboss that your
   application depends on it.

For more information visit:
[jboss 7 classloader](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7)
[jboss 7 deployment descriptors](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+AS7.1)